# iPad 2 with Bluetooth Barcode Scanner

Tags: ios, ipad, barcode-scanner

I've been searching for a while on a way to read data from a barcode scanner into my iPad 2 application but I can't seem to find some sample code that indicates how. All I need is to know the API to use. I saw some sample code on GameKit but before I spend hours trying to learn an API that doesn't do what I want, I am hoping someone will point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPad 2 features a camera that you can try to use to scan bar codes. ZBar will be a good starting library, and it's open source with examples.

Comment: The cameras on the iPad 2 don't have autofocusing so ZBar doesn't work, I tried. Most other scanner APIs seem to rely on the autofocusing feature as well. If you know any that don't please let me know.

Comment: Actually I tried ZBar works on iPad2. I've been able to scan some barcodes eventhough that's not very usable cause of the autofocusing missing.

Comment: What are you saying? It takes longer for ZBar to scan the barcode? Or does ZBar scan some barcodes and not others.

Comment: Turns out the iPad2 I had was faulty. I finally found someone else with an iPad2 and tried my app (using ZBar) on there and it scanned fine. I never considered my iPad2 would have a manufacturer error, I guess I thought Apple was beyond those kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html) to scan bar codes?

Comment: The cameras on the iPad 2 don't have autofocusing so ZBar doesn't work, I tried. Most other scanner APIs seem to rely on the autofocusing feature as well. If you know any that don't please let me know.